# Are BRIN indexes an alternative to table partitioning?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, bigdata

I need a means of being able to store hundreds of trillions, or millions of billions (quadrillions) of rows and be able to query on them efficiently. When working with MS SQL Server, I could use table partitioning with clustered column store indexes to get query results pretty quickly -- seconds to sub second.

I'm wondering if BRIN indexing could help me accomplish this. Or if a combination of table partitioning and BRIN indexing is necessary.

Comment: Quadrillions?  Really?

Comment: Partitioning is the way to organize your data. Indexes (including BRIN) is the way to store information about your data. In general it is two different things. But in both cases the data nature is essential so your question is too broad IMO.

Answer (score 1):

No.  BRIN indexes require the data to be clustered on the indexed column(s) in order to be effective, but they don't do anything to create or maintain this clustering.  So it needs to line up with how the data is naturally inserted.

Partitioning on the other hand will create/maintain the organization it needs.  For efficiency of insertion, it might be convenient if this aligns with the natural insert order.